# Why SparkSession.sql() is not for SELECT queries?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I‘m pretty curious about that why SparkSession says sql() is not for SELECT Command.

Is there any problem if I insist on doing so?

Thanks for your reply!

```
/**
   * Executes a SQL query using Spark, returning the result as a `DataFrame`.
   * This API eagerly runs DDL/DML commands, but not for SELECT queries.
   *
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  def sql(sqlText: String): DataFrame = withActive {
    val tracker = new QueryPlanningTracker
    val plan = tracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.PARSING) {
      sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan(sqlText)
    }
    Dataset.ofRows(self, plan, tracker)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the docs mean that it eagerly runs DDL/DML commands but it does not eagerly run SELECT queries. That's the nature of Spark's lazy evaluation - it never runs SELECT queries eagerly because they are transformations; it will only include it in a query plan until you call an action.

However, DDL/DML commands are actions, so they will be run eagerly instead.

So, to answer your question, it's totally fine to use `spark.sql` to run SELECT queries. It will return a dataframe for the results of the query.